# How to rename "My Home" tab in My sites

Tags: my-site

We want to rename the "My Home" tab so it says "My Stuff"(!). We're using Sharepoint 2007 - does anyone know how to do this?

Using a javascript hack at the moment; but we really want the change to be done "properly".

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding it to each site individually?  All of the changes I'm familiar with would have to be done on a site by site basis.  You could potentially back some things into the masterpage, but it would have to be deployed to all existing sites.

Here is a great resource for customizing MySite:  http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx

Answer (score 0):

At work we ended up writing our own site map providers that change the my site top nav to say whatever we want it to.